# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil' showing this error while sending parameters to the url

Tags: objective-c

I write this code for sending the below parameters to given url. But it is showing:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

How should I make it correct?

```
NSMutableDictionary *request = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[request setObject:@"Nexus 5" forKey:@"device_name"];
[request setObject:@"device id" forKey:@"device_id"];
[request setObject:[userDict valueForKey:@"mobileNumber"] forKey:@"mobile_number"];
[request setObject:@"1.0.0" forKey:@"app_version"];
[request setObject:@"0.0000" forKey:@"latitude:"];
[request setObject:@"0.0000" forKey:@"longitude"];
[request setObject:[userDict valueForKey:@"otp"] forKey:@"otp_number"];
[request setObject:passwordTxtFld.text forKey:@"password"];


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:request options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *tRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.4:28901/register"]];
[tRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[tRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[tRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:tRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
  {
      NSLog(@"%@",data);
      NSDictionary *userDict1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
      NSLog(@"Result------------ : %@",userDict1);

  }] resume];
```

Comment: Log the `error`. Read the `data` (to convert it into JSON) only if there is no error?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not returning any data, that is why your code isn't working.

Make sure that http://192.168.1.4:28901 is accessible and you're not getting any app-transport errors.

Like this one:
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: I didn't get you animaonline will u pls explain some more please

Comment: Set a breakpoint in dataTaskWithRequest:tRequest completionHandler:^

The data will be nil, most likely the NSError *error will have a value.

Check your log and post it here.